# Trying to overlay custom Tiles in Osmdroid

Tags: java, android, gis, osmdroid

I have a Geotiff I want to put on top of a osm base map.
I tiled the Geotiff via maptiler - the output is a folder with the file structure `resourcename/zoom/x/y.png`

Then I uploaded this filestructure to my webspace and tried to put it in my code like this:

```
final MapTileProviderBasic tileProvider = new MapTileProviderBasic(
    getApplicationContext());
final ITileSource tileSource = new XYTileSource(
    "myGeotiff", null, 14, 16, 256, ".png", "http://mysite.com/");
tileProvider.setTileSource(tileSource);
final TilesOverlay tilesOverlay = new TilesOverlay(
    tileProvider, this.getBaseContext());
tilesOverlay.setLoadingBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
osmv.getOverlays().add(tilesOverlay);
```

When I start the app and try to add my overlay logcat says this over and over:

```
SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

And my tiles are not displayed.

Does anybody have experience with this and can help?

Comment: After some additional research on this I think that osmdroid might be requesting the wrong tiles somehow. I get Nullpointers on some files that are not existing the whole time now.

Comment: Ok now I tried the same approach for a dataset created by the Mobile Atlas Creator, this works - slowly but it works - So my problems seems to be the conversion from Geotiff to tiles that are accepted by osmdroid.
As far as I know my Geotiff is WGS84 and that is what I selected in Maptiler...but somewhere something must have went wrong.

Comment: check the tile names as per the default names. It worked for me when I renamed my custom tiles according to the tile names required. the names are different when created from any of the tools - raj